# Removing margins inside a container

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to remove the margins(maybe I'm using an incorrect term) inside a container?
If you run the code snippet you'll see there's a distance between the left side of the container and the text. Any way to remove that?

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <h2>Hello</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#no-gutters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a `.row`, which deals with the margins.

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```